# How can you combine the full-width laptop admin UI that has a sidebar, with the centered readme / content UI?

Tags: layout

[Here](https://dribbble.com/shots/20717995-Linear-Dashboard-Design) we have the nice and elegant Linear App admin UI stretching full laptop width:

[image]

And here we have a "centered" slim column of text like in a nice clean distraction-free blog post.

[image]

Often times in documentation sites you have the left-sidebar and the content starting from there. Then stuff on the right, like [Vercel's docs site](https://vercel.com/docs/rest-api#introduction/api-basics/authentication) (sorry for the image artifacts, it appears the gif compressor is faulty).

[image]

What are the different techniques you could use with a sidebar and content? I get that on mobile you have the sidebar hidden behind the menu item, but on larger screens, I don't get how you could accomplish centered blog-post-like content (or forms or tables, etc.), and yet still attain the nice look and feel of a left-flush sidebar. How would you combine the two? What are industry best-practices or perspectives here?

[Here](https://atlassian.design/get-started/design/) is a content page embedded in an admin panel, not centered, how can you accomplish centered and make it look nice / mesh well conceptually with the admin UI design paradigm? [Here](https://uxpickle.com/ux-best-practice-for-data-table-cell-content-alignment/) is another center-aligned content area.

Answer (score 0):

I decided on having 4 possible main layout styles in the app (so far, maybe there are 1 or 2 more).

- Fill layout: This goes to a max of ~1500px and then is centered. Shrinks down to mobile.
- Content layout: This goes to a max of ~750px and is then centered. Shrinks down to mobile.
- Split layout: This is 2 equal sized panes, up to ~750px each, down to 500px min, then they stack.
- Sidebar(s) layout: This has a sidebar on two sides of a visibly centered element. There is some complex logic here which required JavaScript, but basically keep the sidebars ~350px each, shrink the center from ~750-500px, then shrink the sidebars to ~300px, then hide the right sidebar, then hide the left sidebar and center the content, shrinking down to mobile.

Can you think of any other major layouts? This would allow for:

- documentation and admin panels (sidebar layout)
- landing pages (fill layout, content layout, and split layout)
- content pages (content layout)

Next up is to figure out how to do navigation properly, putting some at the top, others at the side. But beside the point....